# Awk multiple pipes to different parts

Tags: bash, awk, pipe

I have some data where each line looks more or less like this:

11/11/2013 12:10:10,5000,3000,2000

So with normal awk I would get:

```
$1 = 11/11/2013

$2 = 12:10:10,5000,3000,2000
```

Now I want to pipe these two element to different new awk functions, because $1 needs to be split based upon a forward slash and $2 needs to be split based upon a comma..

However, with

```
awk '{print $1}' $INPUT | awk -F/ '{print $3 "-" $2 "-" $1}'> $OUTPUT
```

I just get access to the date and then Iam already "through the file". How to pipe multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk with multiple field separators also. Consider below code:

```
> s='11/11/2013 12:10:10,5000,3000,2000'
> awk -F '[,/: ]+' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i":"$i}' <<< "$s"
1:11
2:11
3:2013
4:12
5:10
6:10
7:5000
8:3000
9:2000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the `split` function.  No need for a whole new `awk` program:

```
s='11/11/2013 12:10:10,5000,3000,2000'

awk '{split($1,d,"/"); split($2,t,","); print d[3]"-"d[2]"-"d[1]}' <<<"$s"
```

you can do whatever you need to with the components of `t` the same way... `t[1]` for the first, etc.